# How do I install a plugin for Audacity on OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, installation, plugins, audacity

I'm trying to install one of these plugins.

http://audacity.sourceforge.net/download/nyquistplugins

The there is only a .txt and a .ny file.

The instructions ( http://audacity.sourceforge.net/download/plugins ) mention putting it in a plugins folder, but I don't see said folder.

Comment: Where have you looked for the folder so far?

Comment: Applications, and also inside the Audacity.app folder. instructions are not very specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Plug-ins: `/Applications/Audacity/Plug-ins/`. The Audacity DMG comes with a folder called `plug-ins` as well. I guess you're meant to manually create `/Applications/Audacity/` for the contents of the DMG.

As usual, audio units can be added to `/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components/` and VSTs to `/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST/`.